# Reading String Until Blank Space

Tags: arrays, c, string, gcc, io

I am working on a C program that will read user input as Strings separated by spaces. I wanted a way to read these strings up until the blank spaces. I know that scanf does this with ease, but I was wondering if it was possible to do the same with gets() or sscanf() or some combination of the 2. I am very new to C, only having just started it and I come from a Java background. Thank you all in advance, I really appreciate any and all help!!!! Find below the code I have so far as well as well as a sample input (***The wanted functionality is achieved if the scanf() portion is uncommented, but the goal is achieve the same functionality as scanf() only using gets() and sscanf()).

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter words seperated by spaces:(. or EOF to stop):\n");

    do
    {
        char s[255];
        //scanf("%s",s);
        gets(s);
        if(strcmp(s,".")==0 || strcmp(s,"EOF")==0)
        {
            insert_dictionary_order(s);//adding to list
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            insert_dictionary_order(s);//adding to list
        }
    }
    while(1);
    //now printing list
    print_list();
    return 0;
}
```

```
This is a sample text.
The file will be terminated by a single dot: .
The program continues processing the lines because the dot (.)
did not appear at the beginning.
. even though this line starts with a dot, it is not a single dot.
The program stops processing lines right here.
.
You won't be able to feed any more lines to the program.
```

Edit: The answer MUST implement either get() or sscanf() or both.

Answer (score 1):

First, Never, Ever, Ever use `gets()`. It is so insecure and prone to exploit by buffer overflow it has been completely removed from the c-library beginning with C11. See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102) (using `scanf()` with the `"%s"` or `"%[..]"` conversion specifiers without the optional *field-width* modifier are just a bad)

`fgets()` is what you are looking for. To read your text file, stopping when `'.'` appears alone as the first character in a line with nothing following (aside from the `'\n'` included in the buffer by `fgets()`), you simply read each line into a sufficiently sized buffer (character array) and check the first character in the line to see if it is a `'.'` and check the second character to see if it is `'\n'`, and if so, exit your read-loop.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC];    /* buffer to hold line */
    
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {         /* read each line */
        /* if 1st char '.' and either EOF or next is '\n', done */
        if (*line == '.' && (!line[1] || line[1] == '\n'))
            break;
        line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;         /* trim \n from end of line */
        puts (line);                            /* output line */
    }
}
```

(**note:** above `strcspn (line, "\n")` returns the number of characters in `line` up to the `'\n'` allowing you to overwrite the `'\n'` with the *nul-termianting* character to remove it)

Generally checking that the second character in the line beginning `'.'` is a newline would be sufficient, but there are a number of editors that do not write POSIX compliant files (meaning no `'\n'` after the final line). If you didn't check against `EOF`, then for files with non-POSIX file endings, you would output the last `'.'` if it appeared on the final line.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in `dat/stop_on_dot.txt` redirected to the program on `stdin` as input, you would receive the following:

```
$ ./bin/stop_on_dot < dat/stop_on_dot.txt
This is a sample text.
The file will be terminated by a single dot: .
The program continues processing the lines because the dot (.)
did not appear at the beginning.
. even though this line starts with a dot, it is not a single dot.
The program stops processing lines right here.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `gets`, there is no check for boundary there.

As for your concern using just `getchar()` is enough by checking the input is space character( , `\t`,`\n`)
I have just written a small program to take input till the space.
we can write it more robustly, let me know if this solves your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    while(ch = getchar())
    {
        if(ch != ' ' && ch != '\t' && ch != '\n')
            putchar(ch);
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```